# ¿Cómo hacer la siguiente petición por PHP para recuperar un JSON?

Tags: php, json

Estoy tratando de realizar una petición a una URL que me tiene que devolver un JSON, y me han proporcionado los siguientes datos (los censuro un poco)

URL del servicio web: https://www.misitio.es/actividad.php

Petición JSON:

```
 {
  "Auth": {
    "user": "realuser",
    "pass": "secret",
    "time": 666666,
    "action": "getObject",
    "Data_HASH": ""
  },
  "Request": {
    "id_final": 897,
    "id_panel": 156,
    "id_punto": 16,
    "id_lang": 0,
    "id_seccion": 4
  }
}
```

El caso es que he estado mirando en Internet y veo ejemplos de cómo hacerlo, pero encuentro sólo peticiones más sencillas, donde solo se envía usuario y contraseña y me piero. ¿Podéis echarme una mano a realizar esta petición?

Muchas gracias

Comment: Que has intentado hacer? Has utilizado algo como curl? O necesitas utilizar algo en concreto?

Comment: Lo he intentando con CURL, pero necesito hacerlo en PHP con un POST o similar

Comment: CURL es PHP y permite hacer peticiones POST.

Comment: Me refiero a que lo que necesito es pintar los datos del JSON que me devolverá esa petición en una página, pero no consigo enviar la petición desde un fichero .php, desde el servidor ejecutando CURL he llegado más lejos que picándolo en un PHP que es donde no consigo hacer funcionar nada...

Comment: Te doy la bienvenida a Stackoverflow. El problema es que ni siquiera nos aclaramos sobre qué es lo que quieres. Se entiende que vas a lanzar una petición al servidor y que éste te devolverá en respuesta un JSON ¿cierto? 1º. ¿Qué estás implementando del lado del cliente para hacer la petición y manejar la respuesta? ¿Desde el cliente hay que enviar algo al servidor, algún dato? ¿Cuál es tu código de envío al servidor? 2º. En el servidor puedes usar cURL, o puedes recibir los datos por simple POST o GET, manejarlos y devolver la respuesta al cliente... ¿qué código tienes al respecto?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Puedes hacer la petición con CURL o utilizar `file_get_contents()`, de la siguiente manera:

> CURL

```
$url = 'https://www.misitio.es/actividad.php';

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
$result = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);

$data = json_decode($result);
```

> file_get_contents()

```
$result = file_get_contents($url);
$data = json_decode($result);
```

Para hacer una petición POST y enviar datos en CURL sólo tienes que añadir un par de líneas a lo anterior:

```
$json = '{...}';

$url = 'https://www.misitio.es/actividad.php';

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Content-Type: application/json'));
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $json);
$result = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);

$data = json_decode($result);
```

Comment: Esto lo entiendo, pero como envío los datos que tengo que enviar para que me devuelva los datos? Para que funcione, yo le tengo que enviar lo que puse arriba en el post, es donde tengo el problema...

Comment: He actualizado la respuesta para que veas cómo hacer ese POST.

Comment: Gracias, voy a intentarlo con esto que me indicas, únicamente que por un lado tengo los datos de "Auth" y por otro "Request", debo de hacer un array dentro de otro?

Comment: Piensa que no sé cómo se maneja la petición cuando llega al servidor. Tienes un JSON, que no deja de ser un string, así que quizá lo que necesitas saber es cómo manejar ese JSON cuando es recibido por el servidor. Yo enviaría `'postvar1' => $json` y decodificaría `$_POST['postvar1']` en el servidor.

Comment: Ahí está el tema, que yo no tengo acceso al servidor al que hago la petición, me han dado los mismos datos que he puesto en el post inicial y me las tengo que arreglar. Gracias por tu ayuda!

Comment: Tendrá que haber documentación de qué debe recibir el servidor para entender la petición, sino va a ser difícil... No hay de qué.

Comment: Lo que ves en el primer post es lo que debe recibir, de hecho acabo de conseguir que me devuelva lo que quiero haciéndolo por SSH desde el servidor con curl --header "Content-Type: application/json"  --request POST  --data '{  "Auth": {    "user": "realuser",    "pass": "secret",    "time": 666666,    "action": "getObject",    "Data_HASH": ""  },  "Request": {    "id_final": 897,    "id_panel": 156,    "id_punto": 16,    "id_lang": 0,    "id_seccion": 4  }}' https://www.misitio.es/actividad.php

Comment: Siendo así, debería bastar enviando el json directamente: `curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $json)`, he actualizado la respuesta para que lo veas con más claridad.

Comment: Perfecto! Objetivo conseguido =)